# Why is outlook web duplicating emails in my inbox?

Tags: email, outlook-on-the-web

I use Outlook web (not the desktop app) and I seem to have suddenly been posed with an irritating issue (maybe some setting got changed)

Whenever I reply to an email conversation (I've the "Group emails" setting ON), I noticed that the **inbox** shows two emails on every successful outgoing email (screenshot below)

[image: duplicates]

This happens for every email that I reply to, so it's not an intermittent or network issue. Any idea which setting I should be turning off to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have a rule that your email is in the BCC, CC or TO field? Because that would place this email both in the inbox and sent items. The group email setting would see the conversation and place both in the same view.

Comment: @LPChip `Do you have a rule that your email is in the BCC, CC or TO field?` Where will I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

When Outlook begins its Send/Receive process, a faulty email message on the mail server causes duplicate emails to be created. You can get into the web interface of the email server to delete the corrupt/damaged email that is causing all the duplicates in order to fix this.

Comment: That's a bummer. I'm guessing only an Admin might have access to the web interface of the server

Comment: @asprin - Likely correct answer in this comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/167231/why-is-outlook-web-duplicating-emails-in-my-inbox#comment153853_167231 This "answer" is anything but, it's only wild speculation.